# Scala, enforce length of Array/Collection parameter

Tags: scala, types

Suppose I have a class defined as

```
case class MyClass(myArray: Array[Int])
```

I want to only allow instances where the myArray parameter is of a specific length, say 3.

1. Can I enforce that `myArray.size == 3` at type/compile level?
2. Would it be different with another collection? (say, an immutable list)

The only way I found to this is via a smart constructor at runtime, checking the size of myArray and failing - using for instance `require`.

Comment: Take a look to: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/sized.scala and https://github.com/travisbrown/sized and https://github.com/fthomas/refined

Answer (score 6):

> Can I enforce that myArray.size == 3 at type/compile level?

Yes Scala can [represent numbers at type-level](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/4742767df51b4147cfd9e3cbd8228e8d23e2ce3f/library/src/scala/compiletime/ops/int.scala#L4). For example, using [`Sized`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#collections-with-statically-known-sizes) from shapeless

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.sized._
import nat._

case class MyClass(myArray: Sized[Array[Int], _3])
MyClass(Sized[Array](1,2,3))         // ok
MyClass(Sized[Array](1,2,3,4))       // compile-time error

Array(1,2,3,4).sized(3).map(MyClass) // None
```

Here is how you might go about it in Scala 3 using `scala.compiletime.ops` facilities

```
import scala.compiletime.ops.int.S

enum MyArray[Size, +A]:
  case Nil extends MyArray[0, Nothing]
  case Cons[N <: Int, B](head: B, tail: MyArray[N, B]) extends MyArray[S[N], B]

import MyArray._

val xs: MyArray[3, Int] = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)))
val ys: MyArray[4, Int] = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Cons(4, Nil))))

case class MyClass(myArray: MyArray[3, Int])
MyClass(xs) // ok
MyClass(ys) // compile-time error
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use require with everything you want :)

```java
case class MyClass(myArray: Array[Int]) {
  require(myArray.size == 3, "Only arrays with 3 items are allowed!")
}
```

In case you pass an array that does not meet the requirement, it will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is exactly what I meant with 'smart constructor'. I will update my question to make it clear 

Comment: @ticofab this does NOT provide compile-time checking. This will throw a runtime exception, as an `IllegalArgumentException` when the require check fails