# Is it possible to control the number of argument in a function when using varargs in compile time(Scala)?

Tags: scala, scalaz, shapeless, scala-cats, zio

Let us suppose, we have to create the `OddList[+T]` which contains only odd number of elements.
Now can we do something like this

```
OddList(1,2) //Works fine
OddList(1,2,3) //Compilation error
```

if there is no condition of odd/even then we would simply do as below

```
object OddList{
 def apply[T](eles: T*) = ...
}
```

But can we control number of arguments that could be passed?

Comment: I am not sure what you did understand and what you didn't . Could you please elaborate what you understand and what you didn't so that I can edit my question accordingly?

Comment: I bet it's possible with a macro. [This old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17387140/574815) gives an example of a macro transformation of a method that takes a varargs - should be a good starting point if you want to try that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Dylan and everyone who asked to explore to macros way. I don't know if there are better ways, I would love to know but macros way works for me, at least for now. I tried the below  code and it worked.

```
trait OddArgHolder[T]{
  val args: Seq[T]
}
case class OddArgs[T](args: Seq[T]) extends OddArgHolder[T]

object OddArgHolder{
  import scala.language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

  def applyMacro[T](c: Context)(method: c.Expr[T]*): c.Expr[OddArgHolder[T]] = {
    import c.universe._

    if(method.size % 2 == 0){
      c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Only odd number of arguments allowed")
    } else {
      val met = method.map(m => c.typecheck(m.tree))
      c.Expr(c.parse(s"OddArgs( $met )"))
    }

  }

  def apply[T](method: T*): OddArgHolder[T] = macro applyMacro[T]

}


  println(OddArgHolder(1,2))
 //Compiletime output: 
 //Only odd number of arguments allowed
 //  println(OddArgHolder(1,2))
```

Comment: This answer simply gives _a_ solution that worked for you without generally addressing the actual solution. Ideally there should be documentation or resources that you referenced that helped you get there; the whole point of SO is **not** to provide simply an implementation that works (implementation is a good start though) for you but rather to provide resources that can help people generally with analogous compile-time checking for vararg length requirements.

Comment: Please update your answer (especially if you accept it as the solution) to include reference material that you think might be helpful to someone wanting to learn more about the approach that worked for you. That being said, I'm glad you found something that worked! I wasn't aware of this approach, macros are pretty cool :)

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. If you go through the comments you will find that @Dylan has a given a link where a similar problem has already been solved. I just solve the problem by going though it. The first thing I did in the answer is mentioning his name so that if anyone wants to go through the journey of the solution he can go to Dylan comment and follow the link.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any way of limiting this using some kind of built-in mechanism. A macro can be a possible solution. If you want to keep it simple, the only thing I can think of is that of asking for pairs:

```
object OddList {
 def apply[T](elems: (T, T)*) = ???
}
```

I also think that there might be some confusion with regards to naming, since odd numbers are *2n+1* and even ones are *2n* (because you can split them *evenly* by two -- see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics))). As such, you can define the following:

```
object EvenList {
 def apply[T](elems: (T, T)*) = ???
}

object OddList {
 def apply[T](elem: T, elems: (T, T)*) = ???
}
```

Probably not the most elegant solution, but definitely simple and easy to implement.

If this approach works for you, you can create quite flexible smart constructors as follows:

```
object Even {
  def apply[CC[_], A](
      elems: (A, A)*
  )(implicit factory: collection.Factory[A, CC[A]]): CC[A] = {
    val builder = factory.newBuilder
    for ((first, second) <- elems) {
      builder += first
      builder += second
    }
    builder.result()
  }
}

object Odd {
  def apply[CC[_], A](elem: A, elems: (A, A)*)(implicit
      factory: collection.Factory[A, CC[A]]
  ): CC[A] = {
    val builder = factory.newBuilder
    builder += elem
    for ((first, second) <- elems) {
      builder += first
      builder += second
    }
    builder.result()
  }
}

assert(Even[Set, Int]((1, 2), (3, 4)) == Set(1, 2, 3, 4))
assert(Odd[List, String]("1", ("2", "3")) == List("1", "2", "3"))
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/jg2cuqgrQZ6mB665hWNJtg/43).

As a further improvement, I believe you can also create types to wrap the two possible returned items so that you can reason about collection size parity at compile time (if that is a requirement), but this is not covered by this example.

Comment: Thanks @stefanobaghino for answering. That is a way, but I don't want it to be wrapped with tuples

Answer (score 1):

One question first off: Are you including `Nil` as an element?

Because `(1 :: 2 :: Nil).size` is `2`/even, your other example is `3`/odd

At **compile time**, `shapeless` has `Sized` (see this answer: [Scala, enforce length of Array/Collection parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69184210/5065400)), but that seems to be for static, concrete values.

At **runtime** you can throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when the constructor is called

```scala
    case class OddList[T]( elements: T* ) {
        private val numElements: Int = elements.size
        private val hasOddNumElements: Boolean = numElements % 2 != 0
        require(hasOddNumElements, s"There are an even [$numElements] number of elements!")
    }

    OddList( 1, 2 ) // Runtime exception
    OddList( 1, 2, 3 ) // Works fine
```

Comment: I am willing to bet you can use similar techniques to the ones `Size` uses. There shouldn't be anything fundamentally different to proving at the type-level that some sort of Peano number is `k` or that some Peano number is `2n`.

Comment: Wanted to check it at compilation time. I am able to do it with macros now, see my answer.

Comment: @Jorg W MittagI would explore the way Size uses but macros worked for me now.